# MVC 4 Entity Framework 5 - store and receive images

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

What is the "best" way of handling images with EF5 and MVC (suggestions)?
(I use the code-first approach)

- How should i store them (type) i a local db?

**In my example i want a user store (his/her own) images and also have the choice of picking images from a collection. 
And finally I want my page to display images*.*

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to store images in a SQL DB, store them as BLOBs - there is a good article here: [Storing Images and BLOB files in SQL Server](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3719221/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server.htm).

If this is to be a large project with lots of images though, then you are better off storing the images on a CDN (like Azure Blob Storage) and just store the url and pertinent image info (user, title, size, etc) in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

I think this goes to a more funamental decision. Do you want to store paths (file names) or their bytes in the database?

Both have pros and cons but I personally have found to be more convenient to store paths, which requires adding a simple string property to your business object.

**Showing the image collection**

You could use CKEditor's File Manager to show the collection of images and let the user pick one. The return value of their javascript function returns the image path:

http://labs.corefive.com/projects/filemanager/